# MultiValueDictKeyError Django at /student_form

Tags: django

I am new to Django, I have created a model and trying to post data from the front end.
following is my view.py

```
def studentForm(request):
      userProfile = StudentProfileForm.objects.create(FirstName=request.POST['userFirstName'] LastName=request.POST['userLastName'], GreScore= request.POST['userGreScore'], IELTSTOEFL=request.POST['userIeltsToefl'],WorkEx=request.POST['userWorkEx'],ResearchDone=request.POST['userResearch'])
      userProfile.save()
      return render(request,'register/bg-pages.html')
```

Following is my model

```
class StudentProfileForm(models.Model):
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    GreScore = models.IntegerField()
    IELTSTOEFL = models.IntegerField()
    WorkEx = models.IntegerField()
    ResearchDone = models.IntegerField()
```

Error is following:
Request

```
Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/student_form
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'userFirstName'
Exception Location: C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 79
Python Executable:  C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.1
Python Path:    
['D:\\AB\\UOR_everything\\semester_2(winter_2019)\\Software_Engineering\\login_registration',
 'C:\\Users\\AB\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\AB\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\AB\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\AB\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\AB\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\AB\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 10 Mar 2019 00:35:51 +0000
```

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If one of your `POST` parameters is missing, you will get an error unless you use `.get()` with a fallback parameter. Also, You are missing a `,` in your `.create()` method.

Example:

```
name = request.POST.get('name', '')  # This will get the name value, or be an empty string if empty
```

Try this:

```
def studentForm(request):
    if request.METHOD == 'POST':  # This will protect you against GET requests
        first_name = request.POST.get('userFirstName', '')
        last_name = request.POST.get('userLastName', '')
        gre_score = request.POST.get('userGreScore', '')
        ieltstoefl = request.POST.get('userIeltsToefl', '')
        work_ex = request.POST.get('userWorkEx', '')
        research_done = request.POST.get('userResearch', '')

        # `userProfile.save()` is unnecessary bc `.create()` already does this
        userProfile = StudentProfileForm.objects.create(FirstName=first_name, LastName=last_name, GreScore=gre_score, IELTSTOEFL=ieltstoefl, WorkEx=work_ex, ResearchDone=research_done)

        return render(request,'register/bg-pages.html')
```